# What does volitional form + っと mean?

Tags: verbs, volitional-form

> 「そうだ！家で音楽聞こうっと」
>
> 「もう寝ようっと」
>
> 「英語でブログを書いてみようっと。」

How does it differ from a volitional form without っと?

My best guess is that it's a monologue marker, like な is.

Comment: Yes, kind of...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it's a sentence-ending particle which is usually used in monologues. [One article](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110008799626) says the main function of this っと is to casually convince/confirm something to the speaker themselves. Perhaps it's like saying 'okay' to yourself.

> - これで良しっと。
> - 今日も1日お疲れさまでしたっと。 (before going to bed, to oneself)

Occasionally it's used when there's an actual listener. When that happens, it expresses the speaker's sarcasm or indifference to the matter or the listener.

> - 俺はもう知らないっと。 I don't care any more.
> - 「彼女ができたんだ。」「そりゃよかったねっと。」  (indifferently)

Comment: Can we think of it as if there was an omitted する or 思うafter と?

Comment: @max It may be from a quotative-と in its broadest sense, but I think it's better to treat this as a distinct sentence-end particle.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it sounds to me like a shortened version of と思います, something like "I think I will...".

> 「英語でブログを書いてみようと思いました。」
>
> I thought about writing a blog in English.