# What does よし！久しぶりに魚にしようっと！ mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, manga, sentence

So I am reading Dragon Ball in Japanese and I got stuck with this sentence. Goku is looking for food and looks down at a river and says:

> よし！久しぶりに魚にしようっと！

which I think means something like

> Nice! It's been a while since the last time I ate fish!

So I can understand it by context but I would like somebody to break it down for me and explain to me the use of the two に and especially しようっと. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

- よし in this context is closer to "Okay" or "Alright" said when you've decided something. It's defined as 決意する時に発する声 in [this dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/227500/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%88%E3%81%97/).
- 久しぶり is a noun that works as a no-adjective (sometimes also as a na-adjective). There is no single-word equivalent in English. This に after 久しぶり is used to [turn a na-/no-adjective into an adverb](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/adgobi.html).

  > - **久しぶりの**休暇　*first* vacation *in a long time*
  > - **久しぶりに**走る　to run *for the first time in a while*
  >
  > (Note that 休暇 is a noun and 走る is a verb.)
- ～にする is a very common set phrase which has [several meanings](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B). In this case, it means "to decide on ～ (from multiple options)" or "to choose".
- しよう is the volitional form of する.
- For っと, see [What does volitional form + っと mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27744/5010)

Comment: That is so helpful. Thank you very much, I will take a look more calmly tomorrow, but now I can understand it way better. That was a great answer :)