# 体操でもしてこよっと DB Chapter 2

Tags: translation, particle-と, volitional-form, particle-でも

This is Goku translated as: "Alright. Exercise time!".

体操 = excercise

でも = but

して = doing

こよっと = ??

I couldn't find any reference to understand でもして. Also the ending こよっと, I couldn't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: Regarding でも: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21519/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34029/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13463/9831

Comment: See also (regarding volitional+っと): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27744/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28601/9831

Comment: Thanks. I understood now.