# Understanding てっと at the end of sentence

Tags: grammar

> 桐葉「雪妃エレナは分かるんだけど、今日も逢桜は休み？」
>
> ゆめみ「作業日なのに３日もサボリとか……逢桜さんらしくないよね」
>
> 寿季「とはいえLIMEに既読もつかないしな……桐葉の方はどう？」
>
> 桐葉「私も連絡したけど、なしのつぶてよ。茶店のほうも臨時休業中の張り紙があったし」
>
> 寿季「とりあえず心配だから、一言でもいいからメッセージが欲しいってLIMEに書い**てっと**」

I understand the last sentence means "I would send her a Lime that I would like a message, even if it's just a word.", but I don’t know about the てっと part. Could you please explain this usage of てっと (at the end of a sentence)?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27759/9831

Comment: Thank you. Then I wonder what would be the difference between てっと and ようっと?

Comment: Neither てっと nor ようっと is a single unit. Instead, て and よう are each part of whatever came before them in context (i.e., some inflection of the main verb of the sentence), and っと is the sentence ending (a sort of meta comment on the sentence described there. For example, in 「もう寝ようっと」, 寝よう is the volitional form of 寝る, and っと is a sort of meta-comment on the sentence. In your example, 書いて is the te-form of 書く

Comment: The te-form is just a continuation marker here; just as とりあえず indicates, he is not thinking it's the last measure. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60764/5010), too.